# JQuery: How does load event work for images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script>

var html = "";
var imagesArr = [ 
    "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RHUhIkxWXfM/V0knRDiexII/AAAAAAAAAok/gBHYhd4KheAlaPX_LF6rDHkPZ9B4YS6VACLcB/s1600/napolo%2B25%2Bjp.jpg",
    "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-0rDtgu8yH2A/V0knhAVCgyI/AAAAAAAAAoo/zwno2cyB50UKWAlPM41zL--o7OrAKCWHQCLcB/s1600/nike%2B25jp.jpg",
    "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_w5bgf-rTag/V0knJckJ6II/AAAAAAAAAog/NgHKMdhlCCw9his5PGPhPcFRRdwDzTgXACLcB/s1600/jordan25jp.jpg" ];

for ( var i = 0; i < imagesArr.length; i++ ) {

    html += "<div><img src=\"" + imagesArr[ i ] + "\" id=\"img_" + i + "\"></div>";

    $( "#img_" + i ).off();
    $( "#img_" + i ).on( "load", function() {
        console.log( "#img_" + i + " is loaded! Its size is: " + $( "#img_" + i ).width() + "x" + $( "#img_" + i ).height() );
    } );

}

$( "#container" ).html( html );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I use the latest version of JQuery and the latest version of Google Chrome (MacOS Sierra). I try to make JQuery's load event work but in my console I get nothing. What's the problem with the code?

Comment: it is because at the time you attach event the img tag is there on dom

Comment: **not on dom, typo in previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

You are binding event to image before adding them to `DOM`;

```
for (var i = 0; i < imagesArr.length; i++) {
    html += "<div><img class="sizeAfterLoad" src=\"" + imagesArr[ i ] + "\" id=\"img_" + i + "\"></div>";
}

$("#container").html(html);
$(function(){
    $(".sizeAfterLoad").off('load').on('load', function() {
        console.log("#" + $(this).attr('id')  + " is loaded! Its size is: " + $(this).width() + "x" + $(this).height());
    });
});
```

Comment: Hm. That works! But I don't understand how does it work :) Can you explain me in short words? What does mean "$(function(){"? When does it call?

Comment: This `$(function(){ ... });` is short form of `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`; So , basically we are binding events to images using class selector in a single call;

Comment: @JavaRunner still you have any doubts?

Comment: Sounds good :) But why does "load" event associated with the img's class? I mean... The class it's just a class I think and it shouldn't have any information on when the image is loaded. Why does load event call when our image loads?

Comment: jQuery binding `load` event with the elements selected by `.sizeAfterLoad`; and this event fries as soon image loaded by browser;

Comment: too hard for me :) It's the class loaded not the image loaded... :) You mean the class will be loaded only when the image will be loaded?

Comment: Here class selector we are using to pick elements from the `DOM` using `jQuery` and then binging `load` event to picked elements and the `load` event fires when image get loaded in browser;

Comment: Now you got it;